# создание сессии без команды app

Tags: node.js

Начал изучать NodeJS, споткнулся о сессии

```
//vars
var sessionArray;

//extention
var express     = require('express');
var session     = require('express-session');
var app         = express();
    app.use(session({secret:sessionKey,saveUninitialized:true,resave:true}));

//app
app.get('/superpage',function(request,response){
    sessionArray=session;
    if(sessionArray.datatime){
    }else{
        sessionArray.datatime = Math.random();
    }
    console.log(sessionArray.datatime);     

    response.end("");
});
```

вот эта часть кода полностью работает у меня. Захожу в разных браузерах на одну страницу, и жму F5. В консоле вырисовывается разная переменная, браузер1 - переменная 1, браузер2 - переменная 2 (как и должно быть).

Конкретно у меня в приложении используется структура, где за каждую страницу отвечает функция

```
function start(response, extendData1, extendData2){
    sessionArray=session;
    if(sessionArray.datatime){
    }
    else{
        sessionArray.datatime = Math.random();
    }
    console.log(sessionArray.datatime);

    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
    response.end();
}
```

[примерно как тут](http://www.nodebeginner.ru/)

Возникла проблема, в моем случае у всех переменные в сессии одинаковые.

Вопрос - может ли кто, диагностировать, что написано неправильно?

Comment: МБ стоит переменную 'sessionArray' сделать локальной?

Comment: @user235731var  sessionArray=session

Comment: пробовал, к сожалению эффекта нет

Comment: У вас первый код точно так же не должен работать. Где-то вы опечатались...

Comment: опечатки нет. взять первый пример, возможно ли там создать и использовать сессию без app ? вот в инете ни одного примера ( те что связаны с БД - не считаются )

Comment: Повторяю: ваш первый пример - нерабочий!